# How can I read constantly updated value from external database with room?

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-livedata

I use room with Live Data to access external database.
The value stored in external database is updated by another application every 5 seconds.
It seems that I can't constantly receive the updated value from room.
Should I rebuild database to get updated value every 5 seconds?

Here are some reference code:

```
@Dao public interface GasDynamicDao {

@Query("Select * from gas_dyamic")
LiveData<List<GasDynamicEntity>> getAllInformation();

@Query("Select * from gas_dyamic")
List<GasDynamicEntity> getAllInformationSync();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(List<GasDynamicEntity> products);

@Query("Select * from gas_dyamic where Device_ID = :deviceID")
LiveData<GasDynamicEntity> loadGas(String deviceID);
@Query("Select * from gas_dyamic where Device_ID = :deviceID")
GasDynamicEntity loadGasSync(String deviceID);
```

}

```
public static GasDatabase buildDatabase(final Context appContext, final AppExecutors executors) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, GasDatabase.class,
            DATABASE_FULL_PATH).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}
```

Comment: Another application is black box to me. I can't modify the code.

Comment: I only know the filepath of database it changes and document about its format. And I want try to use Room + LiveData to replace ContentProvider.

Comment: I don't know implementation of "other app" . I want to use new technology(android architecture components) to read database and show them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by polling database.
But database needs not to be recreated or reloaded from room.
LiveData will change again by re-querying database through Dao methods.